# Connecting buttons in main storyboard to @IBAction func operate() in ViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uibutton, ibaction

I'm new to Swift and is trying out the beginner's project of building a calculator. The image below shows what stage I am up to.

However, I have just noticed that every single one of my operator buttons (except ÷) are not connected to the `@IBAction func operate(sender: UIButton){}`. How to connect those buttons to the `@IBAction func operate(sender: UIButton){}`?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check what outlets your buttons are connected to by right clicking on them. To connect a button to an action, hold down control while clicking and dragging from the button to the action you want to attach it to.

Comment: Thank you so much for the advice! It finally worked!! do you mind if I ask another question? if I want to bulk connect multiple button to the same IBAction, how can it be achieved?

Comment: Have to drag them one by one, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 3, you'd like to change the `@IBAction`'s argument from default `(_ sender: Any)` to `(_ sender: UIButton)` or `(_ sender: AnyObject)`, but manually.

It might work.